# JavaScript (Find Minimum in Rotated Sorted Array)

Tags: javascript

I have a leetcode question that I tried to use my own method to solve it, but I got an error and I don't know what's wrong.

This is the topic:
[image]

This is my attempted solution:

```
var findMin = function(nums) {
    if (nums.length === 0) return undefined;
    var minEle = nums[0];
    if (nums.length === 1) {
        minEle = nums[0];
        return minEle;
    }
    var start = 0;
    var end = nums.length - 1;
    if (nums[end] > nums[start]) {
        end = Math.floor(end / 2);
    } else {
        start = Math.ceil(end / 2);
    }
    findMin(nums.slice(start, end + 1));
};

findMin([3,4,5,1,2]);
```

and the output is undefined.

I tried this too :

```
var findMin = function(nums) {
    if (nums.length === 0) return undefined;
    var minEle = nums[0];
    if (nums.length === 1) {
        minEle = nums[0];
        return minEle;
    }
    var start = 0;
    var end = nums.length - 1;
    if (nums[end] > nums[start]) {
        end = Math.floor(end / 2);
    } else {
        start = Math.ceil(end / 2);
    }
    findMin(nums.slice(start, end + 1));
    return minEle;
};

findMin([3,4,5,1,2]);
```

And the output is 3.

I tried to debug it and I got this:

[image]

I don't understand why my recursion solution is not correct. Note that I tried to implement a solution with consideration of time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the last return statement when recursing.

```
return findMin(nums.slice(start, end + 1)); //added return here
```

```js
var findMin = function(nums) {
    if (nums.length === 0) return undefined;
    var minEle = nums[0];
    if (nums.length === 1) {
        minEle = nums[0];
        return minEle;
    }
    var start = 0;
    var end = nums.length - 1;
    if (nums[end] > nums[start]) {
        end = Math.floor(end / 2);
    } else {
        start = Math.ceil(end / 2);
    }
    return findMin(nums.slice(start, end + 1));
};

console.log(findMin([3,4,5,1,2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the smallest value in an array, just use `Math.min`.

**Example:**

```js
console.log(Math.min.apply(null, [3,4,5,1,2]))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried to implement a solution with consideration of Time Complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think recursion is necessary for this one.  At a high level we just need to go through each element and find the smallest.  This could be done pretty simply with a for loop and a variable to store the smallest seen value.

```js
var findMin = function(nums) {
    if(nums.length === 0) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if(nums.length === 1) {
        return nums[0];
    }
    // initialize the smallest number placeholder to the first value
    let smallestNum = nums[0];
    
    for(let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(smallestNum > nums[i]) {
            smallestNum = nums[i];
        }
    }
    return smallestNum;
}
```

This could be simplified with an array reducer, but the logic would be the same.

Another approach could be to assume the numbers will be ascending and once you find a number that is smaller return it.  For example, in `[3,4,5,1,2]` it increases until we go from `5` to `1`.

```js
var findMin = function(nums) {
    if(nums.length === 0) {
        return undefined;
    }
    if(nums.length === 1) {
        return nums[0];
    }

    for(let i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[0] > nums[i]) {
            return nums[i];
        }
    }
    return nums[0];
}
```

In this case as soon as we find a number that is smaller than the first we break the loop.  If we get all the way through the array we know the first number was the smallest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at a rank to comment, so I have to post as an answer. It seems you're changing "end" and "start" in the if conditions, but then you're calling the function again and the function resets those variables to

```
var start = 0;
var end = nums.length - 1;
```

So whatever is changed in the second if/else statement, start will get reset to 0, and end will halve. But maybe I've missed something, so if this is irrelevant please ignore.